# JavaScript __proto__ will affect the original function in the Object?

Tags: javascript, prototype

The function `getBooks` has been defined in the `Author.prototype`. But it can't be used in the `Author` Object. When I am using the `__proto__` to inherits the `Person` property. Why the does the `Author` Object have no `getBooks` function? Is it the effect of `__proto__`?

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
}
function Author(name,books){
    Person.call(this,name);
    this.books = books;
}
Person.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name;
}

Author.prototype.getBooks = function() {
    return this.books;
}

var john = new Person('John Smith');

var authors = new Array();

authors[0] = new Author('Dustin Diaz',['JavaScript Design Patterns']);
authors[1] = new Author('Ross Harmes',['JavaScript Design Patterns']);

authors[0].__proto__ = new Person();

console.log(john.getName());
console.log(authors[0].getName());
console.log(authors[0].getBooks())
```

Comment: You should never use `__proto__` as it's a vendor specific property available in FF & Chrome and not included in the original spec.

Comment: Could you explain in simple terms what you are trying to accomplish? Why are you trying to change the prototype of an instance of Author, instead of chaining the Author prototype to Person?

Comment: @Arkantos Well, s/he could replace `__proto__` with `Object.setPrototypeOf`, but that doesn't change the basic problem with what he is trying to do.

Comment: Thank you all for the help of my question @torazaburo, I just beginning to study the javascript object oriented programming. I try to learn using __proto__ to inherits an object. But I don't really understand too much the usage of the __proto__. Also, I don't know why the variable of Author still can be used. But the function of Author Object can't be used. After, using __proto__  to inherits Person property.

Answer (score 1):

`__proto__` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). Instead assign the prototype of the class to a new instance of the class you're trying to inherit from before adding new prototype methods to that class.

```
function Author(name, books) {
  Person.call(this, name);
  this.books = books;
}

Author.prototype = new Person();
Author.prototype.constructor = Author;

Author.prototype.getBooks = function() {
  return this.books;
};
```

**JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bkmLx30d/1/**

Comment: Yes, as far as the first part of the answer goes, but in terms of the second part, I'm not a huge fan of makeshift multiple-inheritance. Prototypes in theory are supposed to be dynamic, whereas this approach merely takes a static "snapshot" of the current state of the prototypes. It also fails to capture any additional prototypes going up the prototype chain of the "classes" being mixed in. In any case, not quite sure why you would bring this up here, since it doesn't seem to be related to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

you've changed the prototype of the object here  `authors[0].__proto__ = new Person();`, so your first `Author` object in `authors` now has a prototype that's set to a `Person()` object .

when you do  `authors[0].getBooks()`, `authors[0]` will search for `getBooks()` in the prototype but won't find it since `Person.prototype` doesn't have a `getBooks()` and thus give an error.